# How to setup Mockk for an Android project

Tags: gradle, android-jetpack-compose, mockk

I added the mock dependecy to the build.gradle:

```
testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.13.2"
testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-agent-jvm:1.13.2"
```

Now I want to use the import:

```
 io.mockk.*
```

This dosen't work and android studio says:
Unresolved reference: mockk

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was in the androidTest and not the test[UnitTest] folder.